# New to microprofile testing

Tags: ibm-cloud

Good afternoon,
I'm new to IBM CLOUD and I wanted to know what they meant "from get-started directory push your application to the cloud"?

Where are you supposed to type "ibmcloud cf push"?

From the command line, Powershell on Windows, IBM CLOUDSHELL? I'm not sure what they're referring to?

Could anyone help me? Thank you.[ibm-microprofile-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duaZR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first install the IBM Cloud CLI locally, then you'll be able to run the 'ibmcloud' commands:
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cloud-cli-getting-started

Comment: Thank you. I thought I already did that but i will try it again, Thanks.